Error handling in Azure function with custom class
My login function looks like this:
[Function("Loginxyz")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateToken(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "user/login")] HttpRequestData req,
        ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        if (requestData.BarCode != null)
        {
            var localLoginRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<xyz>(requestBody);
            token = await _tokenService.GenerateToken(localLoginRequest);
        }

        if (token == null)
            return new UnauthorizedResult();

        return new OkObjectResult(new { access_token = token });
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        // Handle multiple exceptions
        foreach (var innerException in ae.InnerExceptions)
        {
            log.LogError(innerException, "An error occurred");
            // Handle the inner exception based on its type
        }

        // Return a specific error response based on the aggregate exception
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("An error occurred");
    }
    catch (AuthenticationServiceException ex)
    {
        // Log the error with detailed message
        log.LogError($"Error during token generation: {ex.Message}", ex);

        // Create a custom error response object
        var errorResponse = new
            {
                Error = ex.Message,
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest
            };

        // Return the error response with the appropriate status code
        return new JsonResult(errorResponse) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest };
    }
    catch (LoginConflictException ex)
    {
        // Log the error with detailed message
        log.LogError($"Error during token generation: {ex.Message}", ex);

        // Create a custom error response object
        var errorResponse = new
            {
                Error = ex.Message,
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status409Conflict
            };

        // Return the error response with the appropriate status code
        return new JsonResult(errorResponse) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status409Conflict };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogError($"Error during token generation: {ex.Message}");
        return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}

My service class looks like this:
public async Task<TokenResponseDto> GenerateToken(object tokenRequest)
{
    try
    {
        return await tokenGenerator.GenerateToken(tokenRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw; // Rethrow the exception
    }
}

exception trace:- Function 'Login', Invocation id '': An exception was thrown by the invocation. [2024-07-13T02:28:21.903Z] Result: Function 'Login', Invocation id '': An exception was thrown by the invocation. Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger') [2024-07-13T02:28:21.903Z]    at System.ThrowHelper.Throw(String paramName) [2024-07-13T02:28:21.904Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log(ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args) [2024-07-13T02:28:21.904Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogError(ILogger logger, String message, Object[] args) [2024-07-13T02:28:21.905Z]    at ..AzureFunctions.Funtions.User.LoginFunction.GenerateToken(HttpRequestData req, ILogger log) in \Funtions\User\LoginFunction.cs:line 86 [2024-07-13T02:28:21.907Z]    at ..DirectFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in ..\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators.FunctionExecutorGenerator\GeneratedFunctionExecutor.g.cs:line 38 [2024-07-13T02:28:21.909Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13 [2024-07-13T02:28:21.909Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore\src\FunctionsMiddleware\FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.cs:line 48 [2024-07-13T02:28:21.910Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 89 Stack:    at System.ThrowHelper.Throw(String paramName) [2024-07-13T02:28:21.911Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log(ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args) [2024-07-13T02:28:21.912Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogError(ILogger logger, String message, Object[] args) [2024-07-13T02:28:21.915Z]    at ..Funtions.User.LoginFunction.GenerateToken(HttpRequestData req, ILogger log) in .\Funtions\User\LoginFunction.cs:line 86 [2024-07-13T02:28:21.916Z]    at ..DirectFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in ..\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators.FunctionExecutorGenerator\GeneratedFunctionExecutor.g.cs:line 38 [2024-07-13T02:28:21.917Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13 [2024-07-13T02:28:21.918Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore\src\FunctionsMiddleware\FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.cs:line 48 [2024-07-13T02:28:21.919Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 89. [2024-07-13T02:28:58.728Z] Executed 'Functions.Login' (Failed, Id=b4005c4b-a335-46f7-8dc7-cf24b1d62fe7, Duration=48071ms) [2024-07-13T02:28:58.730Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.Login. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc: Failed to proxy request with ForwarderError: RequestCanceled. System.Net.Http: The operation was canceled. System.Net.Sockets: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.. The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
I throw an error in the tokenGenerator.GenerateToken method and rethrow it in my service class. My expectation is that when I rethrow the error in the service class, it should be caught in my Azure Function, but that's not happening.
However, the error I get from the rethrow is:

An exception was thrown by the invocation.
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger')

I have captured this in my cmd logs.
This is confusing because I was throwing a custom error, not related to ArgumentNullException.
Can someone help me understand this?

Is there a stack trace in the exception?

How did you setup the logging in the function? Seems like the ILogger instance it not there.

@stuartd i added the trace in my question

@PeterBons I contct logger like private readonly ILogger _logger;   public LoginFunction(ILogger logger)
{
_logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
}

So from the stack trace it looks very much like your code in the above comment is throwing the exception, and logger is null. If you need to check that further, just add a line of diagnostic code and run the function again.


Error handling in Azure function with custom class

I do agree with @Peter Bons and to do Error handling with Custom Class follow below steps:
In Program.cs add rith.AddSingleton<RithwikInterface, Test_Rithwik_Class>() and Logging as below:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using FunctionAppRith;

var ri_test = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(rith =>
    {
        rith.AddLogging();
        rith.AddSingleton<RithwikInterface, Test_Rithwik_Class>(); 
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConsole(); 
    })
    .Build();

ri_test.Run();

In Function.cs added :
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace FunctionAppRith
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> ri_lger;
        private readonly RithwikInterface rith_ser;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> lg, RithwikInterface riser)
        {
            ri_lger = lg ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lg));
            rith_ser = riser ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(riser));
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            try
            {
                ri_lger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik");
                var tout = await rith_ser.Tst_Rith_fun();
                var res_out = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                await res_out.WriteStringAsync(tout);
                return res_out;
            }
            catch (CustomException rith)
            {
                ri_lger.LogError(rith, "Hello Rithwik, This is a Custom Error.");
                var res_out = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                await res_out.WriteStringAsync("Hello Rithwik, This is a Custom Error.");
                return res_out;
            }
            catch (Exception rith)
            {
                ri_lger.LogError(rith, "Hello Rithwik, This is a unexpected Error.");
                var res_out = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                await res_out.WriteStringAsync("Hello Rithwik, This is a unexpected Error.");
                return res_out;
            }
        }
    }
    public interface RithwikInterface
    {
        Task<string> Tst_Rith_fun();
    }
    public class Test_Rithwik_Class : RithwikInterface
    {
        public async Task<string> Tst_Rith_fun()
        {
            throw new CustomException("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Created an Exception/Error");
        }
    }
    
    public class CustomException : Exception
    {
        public CustomException(string message) : base(message) { }

    }
}

Output:


In try {} block, you  use your login code then test it.
